# Items in Sitecore history table have incorrect creation date

Tags: sitecore

Curious why I couldn't get any items back from

```
HistoryManager.GetHistory(database, fromThisDate, toThisDate)
```

, I looked in the Sitecore database and found that the "Created" column for each record contained an incorrect datetime.  All datetimes were ahead of the actual datetime by about 6 hours.  I checked the "Items" table, just to see if all of the dates might be off, but those dates were accurate.  This is in my local environment.  Any ideas as to why this might be and/or how to fix would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The history table powers a number of synchronization features across multiple instances of Sitecore. For example, when you publish an item, the event is temporarily stored in the history table so that other instances know to rebuild indexes and clear caches.

Because of this, it's important that the dates are stored in [Coordinated Universal Time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) (UTC), as your delivery servers may exist in different time zones. You are likely seeing the UTC dates for the US Central Time Zone which is 6 hours behind GMT.

The fix would be to pass in UTC dates into the `GetHistory()` method as follows:

```
HistoryManager.GetHistory(database, 
                          fromThisDate.ToUniversalTime(), 
                          toThisDate.ToUniversalTime());
```

Comment: A bit of extra background info: http://www.cognifide.com/blogs/sitecore/help-sitecore-history-engine-does-not-index-some-of-my-items/